# Redux-Thunk: async dispatch is not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to build an app in react native that is suppose to take take two inputs by a user and then make a query to an api and get information about the two inputs. I have been having trouble with `redux` and `redux-thunk` and specifically with `async` actions.

This is the code in my app that i am specifically having trouble with

```
export const fetchData = url => {
  console.log("start Fetching");
  return async dispatch => { // this is where the problem is
    dispatch(fetchingRequest());
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10");
      const json = await response.text();
      if (response.ok) {
        dispatch(fetchingSuccess(json));
        console.log("JSON", json);
      } else {
        console.log("fetch did not resolve");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(fetchingFailure(error));
    }
  };
  console.log("Fetched data");
};
```

Upon debugging the function, I have ended with finding that when the `fetchData` function is called the function will execute but the `async dispatch` that is being returned has `undefined` behavior.

The output in the debugger when the function is called should be

```
start Fetching
JSON file information/Error
```

but the output in the debugger is actually

```
start Fetching
```

Comment: is this error get solved?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply using Promise syntax?

```
  fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10")
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        // do something
      }
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('fetch did not resolve'));
```

Comment: i did not have problem with the try and catch block style of syntax, so it became a habit.